# Connect to Active Directory to get the available meeting rooms

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have an organization active directory, that contains the user data and so on. It also contains the data of the meeting rooms that exist in the organization.

The code in the solution already uses the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace to get the users information and so on, it uses `PrincipalContext`.

Is there is any function or property in the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace that enables me to get all the meeting rooms that exist in Active Directory of the organization?

Active Directory is on a server that is different from the server that hosts the C# application

Edits are welcome, and feedback if the question is not clear enough

Comment: What are your "meeting rooms" stored as? AD has a clear list of possible object types it supports (like User, Group, Container, Computer etc.) - what are those "meeting rooms"?

Comment: Usually this data is actually stored in Exchange. Active Directory will have basic account info, but it's just there as an indication to Exchange for what resources to track; Exchange keeps the actual calendar.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn  so if the active directory exists as an indication to exchange for what resource to track ,,, is it possible to read the data of that resource from the active directory that indicates the exchange , using the name space which i mentioned in the question ??